# Recommendation for Laravel 5.3 stand-alone filemanager/upload

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, upload, laravel-5.3

I'm laravel noob, I am using Laravel 5.3. I want to add image uploader and image manager on my Laravel project so I can reuse uploaded images in form or upload new image. Anyone have recommendation component/plugin or example for my case?

I've tried Responsive FIlemanager (http://responsivefilemanager.com/) but failed to integrate it with laravel.

Sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you look at Spatia Media Library @ https://github.com/spatie/laravel-medialibrary.

Might be exactly what you're looking for and I had no issue integration it into multiple projects. I would also recommend that you plan your application with care and referring to the library documentation, as there are certain aspects that are difficult to acheve out of the box (for instance on the fly image cuts and image cut re-use).